# What if a tag that I asked a question in is used by very few people

Tags: discussion, tags, views

If I asked a question, and almost nobody looks (or has interest) in the tag, and I receive very little views (and possibly no answers), what should I do to expose my questions?

Comment: Have you created a vertically-challenged tag?

Comment: I do not quite understand you by a 'vertically challenged tag'. Sorry.

Comment: Which tag is it?

Comment: Related: [How do I get attention for old unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: @jyoon Peter was making a joke, "vertically challenged" means very short because you said "almost nobody looks"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step one would be to check if your questions is as good as it can be. Is all necessary information there? Is it tagged properly? Are there more relevant tags that might attract the attention of the right people? If your question can be improved, update your question. This will also have the result that your question gets bumped to the front page again, giving it extra attention. A word of advice: don't abuse this, but make your edits substantial. You don't want to annoy people with needless bumps.

If that doesn't work for you, [the next option is a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) if you have 75 rep or more. Offering a portion of your reputation up to advertise your question might give it some extra attention and a possible answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the "share" link to publicise the question on social media (Facebook, Twitter, Google+ and the like), other relevant forums where people interested in the tag might hang out. There are even [badges for that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer).
2. Raise a bounty. This will put it on the "featured" tab.

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the answers above, you can try to add additional, related, and well-viewed tags to the questions.